# Query parameters disappearing Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, query-string

I'm trying to create a link to unsubscribe from a newsletter using Next.js. The idea is, an unsubscribe link can be attached to the newsletter, with a format like

`https://www.example.com/newsletter?reason=unsubscribe&id=jFD8vb6Jy855EPiKZ7NTPReNv8HYDzb4`

with query parameters: reason (unsubscribing) and the id of the unsubscriber.
So, when the page detected the reason being "unsubscribe," it calls a Lambda function that deletes that user, selected by their id, from our database. This works locally, but when testing it live and clicking the unsubscribe hyperlink from the newsletter email, the query parameters disappear. Instead of showing the entire link with query parameters, what is displayed is just

`https://www.example.com/newsletter`,

so the Lambda function can't remove the subscriber from the mailing list. I have a feeling this has something to do with SSR with Next.js, but can't figure out how to fix it. Thanks!

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Button from '../components/Button'
import Footer from '../components/Footer'
import Input from '../components/Input'
import NewsletterState from '../components/NewsletterState'
import Page from '../components/Page'
import StandardNavbar from '../components/StandardNavbar'
import { media } from '../utils/media'

interface EmailPayload {
  email: string
}

export default function Newsletter () {
  const Router = useRouter()
  const [hasSuccessfullySentMail, setHasSuccessfullySentMail] = useState(false)
  const [hasErrored, setHasErrored] = useState(false)
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState } = useForm()
  const { isSubmitSuccessful, isSubmitting, isSubmitted, errors } = formState

  async function onSubmit (payload: EmailPayload) {
    try {
      const res = await fetch('/api/signUpNewsletter', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ ...payload }),
      })

      if (res.status !== 204) {
        setHasErrored(true)
      }
    } catch {
      setHasErrored(true)
      return
    }

    setHasSuccessfullySentMail(true)
  }

  const isSent = isSubmitSuccessful && isSubmitted
  const isDisabled = isSubmitting || isSent
  const isSubmitDisabled = Object.keys(errors).length > 0 || isDisabled

  if (Router.query.reason === 'unsubscribe') {
    async function unsubscribeNewsletter () {
      await fetch('/api/unsubscribeNewsletter', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ id: Router.query.id }),
      })
    }
    unsubscribeNewsletter()
    return (
      <>
        <Head>
          <title>{'Unsubscribe'}</title>
          <meta content="Unsubscribe from newsletter." />
        </Head>
        <StandardNavbar />

        <Page
          title='Unsubscribe Successful'
          description="You will no longer receive our newsletter."
        >
        </Page>
        <Footer />
      </>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <>
        <Head>
          <title>{'Newsletter'}</title>
          <meta content="Sign up for our newsletter." />
        </Head>
        <StandardNavbar />

        <Page
          title="Newsletter"
          description='Enter your email to get weekly updates!'
        >
          <MainDiv>
            <Wrapper>
              {hasSuccessfullySentMail ? (
                <NewsletterState />
              ) : (
                <Form
                  // @ts-expect-error
                  onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
                >
                  {hasErrored && <ErrorMessage>Couldn&apos;t send email. Please try again.</ErrorMessage>}
                  <InputGroup>
                    <InputStack>
                      {errors.email && <ErrorMessage>Email is required</ErrorMessage>}
                      <Input placeholder='Email' id='email' disabled={isDisabled} {...register('email', { required: true })} />
                    </InputStack>
                  </InputGroup>
                  <SubmitButton as='button' type='submit' disabled={isSubmitDisabled}>
                    Sign Up!
                  </SubmitButton>
                </Form>
              )}
            </Wrapper>
          </MainDiv>
        </Page>
        <Footer />
      </>
    )
  }
}

const SubmitButton = styled(Button)`
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 2rem !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
`

const MainDiv = styled.div`
  padding: 5rem;
`

const Wrapper = styled.div`
  flex: 2;
  ${media('<=tablet')} {
    text-align: center;
  }
`

const Form = styled.form`
  & > * {
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }
`

const InputGroup = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  & > *:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 2rem;
  }
  & > * {
    flex: 1;
  }
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 25vw;
  ${media('<=tablet')} {
    flex-direction: column;
    & > *:not(:last-child) {
      margin-right: 0rem;
      margin-bottom: 2rem;
      max-width: 90vw;
    }
  }
`

const InputStack = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  & > *:not(:first-child) {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
  }
`

const ErrorMessage = styled.p`
  color: rgb(var(--errorColor));
  font-size: 1.5rem;
`
```

Answer (score 2):

Could this be the [caveat in the next docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#caveats)?

> Pages that are statically optimized by Automatic Static Optimization will be hydrated without their route parameters provided, i.e query will be an empty object ({}). After hydration, Next.js will trigger an update to your application to provide the route parameters in the query object.

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the response! It definitely sounds like Automatic Static Optimization might be the culprit. Although, it seems as though the "triggering and update to the application" part isn't working. Might some change be needed in the next.config.js file, or is it something else?